# Variable as a Vector and grafics in software R

Tags: r

how to pass it to a vector and compare with the chi-square function. Now i make this:

```
x1<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x2<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x3<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x4<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x5<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x6<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x7<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x8<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x9<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x10<-rnorm(20000,3,2)`

`y1<-((var(x1)*9)/(2^2))
y2<-((var(x2)*9)/(2^2))
y3<-((var(x3)*9)/(2^2))
y4<-((var(x4)*9)/(2^2))
y5<-((var(x5)*9)/(2^2))
y6<-((var(x6)*9)/(2^2))
y7<-((var(x7)*9)/(2^2))
y8<-((var(x8)*9)/(2^2))
y9<-((var(x9)*9)/(2^2))
y10<-((var(x10)*9)/(2^2))
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
x1<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x2<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x3<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x4<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x5<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x6<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x7<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x8<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x9<-rnorm(20000,3,2)
x10<-rnorm(20000,3,2)

y1<-((var(x1)*9)/(2^2))
y2<-((var(x2)*9)/(2^2))
y3<-((var(x3)*9)/(2^2))
y4<-((var(x4)*9)/(2^2))
y5<-((var(x5)*9)/(2^2))
y6<-((var(x6)*9)/(2^2))
y7<-((var(x7)*9)/(2^2))
y8<-((var(x8)*9)/(2^2))
y9<-((var(x9)*9)/(2^2))
y10<-((var(x10)*9)/(2^2))

 y <- c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10)
 x <- c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10)
```

but probably there is a way better option to do it, maybe with a loop or something. Maybe someone else can help you